# VOIP SDK that support voice encryption

Tags: sdk, voip, sip

We need to develop an application that will allow users to communicate through an encrypted channel (ZRTP support will be great). This application should run on Android or Windows mobile. Is there any SDK with voice encryption built-in support? In there is no such SDK for mobile platforms then may be one exists for desktop Windows?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to quickly get up and running on multiple platforms, then I would highly recommend the packages from the folks at 'antisip' (www.antisip.com).

They might not have support for ZRTP, but I know they support at least SRTP (which is an encryption protocol for RTP), and are pretty current, both in terms of SIP protocol support and platforms implemented.

The last company I worked at has successfully implemented VOIP clients on windows, mac, linux, Playstation 3, Android and iPhone with this technology.

Their licensing terms are also very reasonable (distinct all you can eat 'site licenses' per platform, yearly support contracts).

Comment: nice answer Can u please help me with those docs,files .I m a fresher i dnt have much knowledge abt this voice encryption and all so